# Loading remote content into div from URl in attribute value. .

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this doesn't work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".quick-ajax").load($(this).attr('data-url'));

</script>
```

I want every div with class .quick-ajax to load the url in the data-url attribute.

Comment: 1. Use `.data()` to access data attributes. 2. Check your network tab. You have not given sufficient information do help you.

Comment: Because your script doesn't know what `$(this)` is. What's the `id` of the element you're pulling `data-url` from> Do it like this: `$(".quick-ajax").load($('#elementId').attr('data-url'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)` is referring to the window object, not your elements. Try using `.each` to iterate over the elements instead:

```
$(".quick-ajax").each(function () {
   $(this).load($(this).attr('data-url'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the context of this isn't correct.. You should probably just do an each function..

```
$(".quick-ajax").each(function(){
    $(this).load($(this).attr('data-url'));
});
```

Comment: Not to raise a stink, but my answer is identical and was answered 2 minutes before yours. Why is this accepted / present?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was sorted by oldest first. 
Fixed!